# Scroll bar should not be visible when limited rows are present in the grid

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a grid in my view page where i can see a scroll bar.
What i need that when number of rows increase by 10 then the scroll bar should be visible else it should not be visible.
Is it possible in kendoui?

Comment: @anilca, Could you please provide your code and elaborate your scenario what exactly you want in given code?

Answer (score 7):

You can override the default style to hide this.

Try this:

```
.k-grid-content{
    overflow-y: auto    
}
```